# Path to synctex binary in Atom

Tags: binary, latex, atom-editor, pdflatex

I am trying to set up Atom so that I am able to typeset LaTeX documents on it with my mac. I have installed latextools, latex, and and all the vital stuff, but when it comes to having a pdf to view within Atom, I am having trouble. I have the package pdf-view installed, however when “run” my code, the output pdf opens in preview. I believe it has something to do with the package setting for pdf-view, particularly the “Path to synctex binary” space.

I am running macOS Sierra 10.12, and I have MacTeX installed (I believe this comes with TeX Live).